# Operating with template objects

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

**DISCLAIMER** I'm not allowed to use BOOST or any other library, only standard.

In my class `Foo` I've a template function `foo`, which takes 2 parameters: a *pointer-to-object* and a *pointer-to-this-object-member-function*. The `foo` function works with pointer of any class, as you can see. I do NOT know, what class will be passed to it. This function creates an instance of a template structure.

```
template <typename TypeName>
struct Bar
{
    void(TypeName::*action)();
    TypeName* objPtr;
};



template <typename TypeName> void Foo::foo ( void(TypeName::*action)() , TypeName* objPtr )
{
    Bar <TypeName> bar;
    bar.action = action;
    bar.objPtr = objPtr;
};
```

My question is: how do I store objects of `Bar`, created in `foo`, so I can iterate through them later and call the *pointer-to-an-object-member-function* like this:

```
(BarStorage[i].objPtr->*BarStorage[i].action)();
```

Comment: *pointer-to-an-object-member-function* is essentially a *delegate*. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: You're not even allowed to use the standard library, which in C++11 has very good support for [function objects and binding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional)?

Comment: You cannot store instances of `Bar` because `Bar` is a class template, so you cannot make instances of it.

Comment: Only standard is allowed, including C++11.

Comment: So `std::function` and `std::bind` should be sufficient.

Comment: @juanchopanza edited, how do I store OBJECTS of `Bar`. English is not my native language, be kind, don't cavil to my poor vocabulary please

Comment: @Kolyunya same applies. You can only store objects/instances of a `Bar>Something>`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't really know how to say it properly. I create _SOMETHING_ by this code `Bar <TypeName> bar`. What do I store, to access element of this _SOMETHING_ later? Do you understand my problem, do you get, what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use *type erasure*:

```
class BarBase {
    virtual void invoke() = 0;
};

template<typename TypeName>
class Bar final : public BarBase {
    void(TypeName::*action)();
    TypeName* objPtr;
    virtual void invoke() override { (objPtr->*action)(); }
};

class Foo {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BarBase>> myBars;
/* ... */
};

template <typename TypeName>
void Foo::foo ( void(TypeName::*action)() , TypeName* objPtr)
{
    auto bar = new Bar<TypeName>();
    bar->action = action;
    bar->objPtr = objPtr;
    myBars.emplace_back(bar);
};
```

then simply call `myBars[x]->invoke();`

---

To answer questions in comments.

**What's up with `override`?** Explicitly say that you override virtual function from a base class. This is not really necessary here, but is considered good practice. For more details see [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicit_overrides_and_final).

Its a new feature from C++11, some compilers supported this feature in one way or another for a long time, but its been standardized only now. [GCC should support this feature from version 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) - you have to use command line parameter `-std=c++0x`.

**What's up with `unique_ptr`?** It makes life easier. When you allocate `new Bar<XXX>()`, you must at some point say `delete` to free that memory. If you put the pointer in a resource managing object like `unique_ptr`, you no longer need to worry about deleting it. With `vector<BarBase*>` you would have to declare a destructor in `Foo` that does something like:

```
for each element in myBars
    delete element
```

If you use `vector<unique_ptr<BarBase>>`, you don't need to worry about deleting anything. When `vector` is destroyed at end of `Foo`'s life, it will destroy its elements - and `unique_ptr` deletes the memory it contains in its own destructor.

This is also C++11 feature - addition to standard library. You don't have to use it (but then make sure to delete everything at the end).

**What's up with `auto`?** Instead of repeating the same type twice (`Bar<Type> * bar = new Bar<Type>();`), just use it once and let the compiler deduce the correct type of the variable based on the type of the initializer. It behaves exactly the same, its just less typing and looks better :)

Also C++11 feature, supported in GCC since v4.4.

**Why `myBars[x]->invoke()` does the right thing?** Because `invoke` is declared virtual in `BarBase`. This means the method executed is chosen based on the dynamic type (the real type during execution) of `myBars[x]`, not static type. For in-depth explanation, see [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function). There is a minor run-time overhead with this mechanism, but it can't be helped when dealing with dynamic types.

Comment: man, this is an **AWESOME** idea. Gonna try this out! Thanks much.

Comment: @Fiktik, may I ask you some questions concerning your code, please? My compiler g++ doesn't know this syntax with `override` key-word. Is it a new standard or what? I just type  `virtual void invoke() { (objPtr->*action)(); }`. Second: why do you use `unique_ptr`, not just `vector<BarBase*> myBars;`. Third, what is `auto`? Again some new feature in new standard? I just type `Bar<TypeName>* bar = new Bar <TypeName> ( );`

Comment: And the main question: why `myBars[x]->invoke();` calls overridden function and not the base function? `myBars` stores pointers to `BarBase`s, so why not the base function is called?

Comment: @Kolyunya I've added the explanation to the answer.

Comment: @Fiktik, thanks for help and maybe you will find a minute to look at the continuation of the problem here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178280/c-operating-with-template-objects