# C++ Operating with template objects

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, compare

I've a class

```
class BarBase {

};
```

and a derived template class, which stores a pointer to a member function and a pointer to an object of the same class

```
template<typename TypeName> class Bar: public BarBase
{
    void ( TypeName::*action ) ( void );
    TypeName* object;
};
```

I create instances of `Bar` and store pointers to them in the vector of another class `Foo`

```
class Foo {
    private:
        vector<BarBase*> myBars;
    ...
};
```

Now to the question. Foo has a template function

```
template <typename TypeName>
void Foo::foo( TypeName* object , void ( TypeName::*action ) ( void ) )
```

In this function how do I find in `myBars` elements with fields `object` and `action` equal to parameters of this function? As you can see, I can not directly access the fields like `this->myBars[i]->action` since these fields are not (and can not be) members of `BarBase`.

**EDIT**
I do can compare `object`. I add a `virtual size_t getObject (){};` to `BarBase` and override it in `Bar` like `virtual size_t getObject (){ return (size_t)this->object; };`. Then I compare two `size_t` , but I do not know, how to convert `action` to a number...

Comment: There is no correct and simple solution for this problem. You can use dynamic_cast in loop and check, that dynamic_cast returns not null value

Comment: @ForEveR added an update to the question.

Comment: You can cast function pointer to void* using reinterpret_cast, but it's not correct way.

Comment: @ForEveR: A pointer to member function is not a function pointer.

Comment: @aschepler yeah, sorry, but you can convert pointer to member function to void* using reinterpret_cast (in gcc without -pedantic key).

Comment: @ForEveR that may result in undefined behavior , void ptr and member fn pointer are of diff sizes

Comment: actually in your `Foo::foo()`, are you going to call `(object->*action)()` and do not need pointer `object` itself? If so, there might be a way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @ForEveR: You **cannot** convert a pointer-to-member to a `void*` in C++. They might not even have the same size in memory.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas yeah, yeah. it's my fault.

Comment: You're implement type-erasure. You might be interested in [available techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450159/type-erasure-techniques), and in the [interface of `boost::function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost/functionN.html) (or similarly `std::function`). In particular note the `target_type` and `target` members, which offer a `typeid`-based solution (which is an alternative to a `dynamic_cast`-based solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to make the base class polymorphic, and use `dynamic_cast` to determine whether it has the expected type:

```
class BarBase {
public:
    virtual ~BarBase() {}  // virtual function required for polymorphism
};

Bar<TypeName>* bar = dynamic_cast<Bar<TypeName>*>(myBars[i]);
if (bar && bar->object == object && bar->action == action) {
    // it's a match
}
```

This does add some overhead to support RTTI; off the top of my head, I can't think of any well-defined way to do this that doesn't add overhead.

Comment: Note this will never consider a `Bar<Base>` and `Bar<Derived>` the same, even if they contain pointers to the same most-derived object and the same member.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, thanks for an answer, nice solution. May I ask you, why is virtual destructor required and how this conception works? Thanks!

Comment: @Kolyunya: `dynamic_cast` works by using run-time type information (RTTI) to ask the object whether its dynamic type is `Bar<TypeInfo>`. This is only possible if the type is *polymorphic*, which means it has at least one virtual function. If you don't need any virtual functions, then a simple way to achieve this is to make the destructor virtual.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, if you don't want use Mike variant (i prefer his variant).

```
class BarBase 
{
public:
   virtual ~BarBase() { }
   virtual void* getObject() { return 0; }
   virtual const char* getFunctionName() { return 0; }
};

template<typename T>
class Bar : public BarBase
{
public:
   Bar(T* obj, void (T::*func) (void)):object(obj), action(func)
   {
   }
   virtual void* getObject() { return object; }
   virtual const char* getFunctionName() { return typeid(action).name(); }
   T* object;
   void (T::*action)(void);
};
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/d79e33d4597ee209645026b2100330f3

**EDIT.**

Sorry. It's not solution of problem, since `typeid(&S::action).name()` may be equal to `typeid(&S::other_action).name()`.

Also, you can use `dynamic_cast` or `static_cast` not for all objects in vector.

```
class BarBase 
{
public:
   virtual ~BarBase() { }
   virtual void* getObject() const { return 0; }
};

template<typename T>
class Bar : public BarBase
{
public:
   Bar(T* obj, void (T::*func) (void)):object(obj), action(func)
   {
   }
   virtual void* getObject() const { return object; }
   T* object;
   void (T::*action)(void);
};

for (auto pos = objects.begin(); pos != objects.end(); ++pos)
{
      if ((*pos)->getObject() == &p)
      {
         auto bar = static_cast<Bar<S>*>(*pos);
         if (bar->action == act)
         {
            // right object founded.
         }
      }
   }
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/87473a94411997914906c22ef0c31ace